# Replace char at specific substring

Tags: java, replace, substring

first of all I want to say that I am kinda new to Java. So please be easy on me :)

I made this code, but I cannot find a way to change a character at a certain substring in my progress bar. What I want to do is this:

***My progressbar is made out of 62 characters (including |). I want the 50th character to be changed into the letter B (uppercase).It should look something like this: |#########----B--|***

I tried several things, but I dont know where to put the line of code to make this work. I tried using the substring and the replace code, but I can't find a way to make this work. Maybe I need to write my code in a different way to make this work? I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

```
   int ecttotal = ectcourse1+ectcourse2+ectcourse3+ectcourse4+ectcourse5+ectcourse6+ectcourse7;
   int ectmax = 60;
   int ectavg = ectmax - ecttotal;

   //Progressbar
   int MAX_ROWS = 1;

   for (int row = 1; row == MAX_ROWS; row++)
     {
           System.out.print("|");
         for (int hash = 1; hash <= ecttotal; hash++)
           System.out.print ("#");
         for (int hyphen = 1; hyphen <= ectavg; hyphen++)
           System.out.print ("-");
           System.out.print("|");
     }
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Please post only the code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: How should the result look? Like `|###########-|      B`?

Comment: the result should look like |#######----B---|(the progress bar is 62 characters long and I want the letter B to show up as the 50th character)

Comment: Strings are immutable (meaning they can't change) so your best bet is to check out StringBuilder or StringBuffer in the JavaDoc they're pretty easy to understand and are mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell a little more what you want. Because what i sea it that, that you write some string into console. And is not way to change that what you already print to console.
Substring you can use only at String varibles.

If you want to change lettir with substring method in string varible try smth. like this:

```
String a="thi is long string try it";
if(a.length()>50){
    a=a.substring(0,49)+"B"+a.substring(51);
}
```

Other way to change charater in string is to use string builder like this:

```
StringBuilder a= new StringBuilder("thi is long string try it");
a.setCharAt(50, 'B');
```

Sure you must first check the length of string to avoid the exceptions.

I hope that I helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically I want this to be printed out. |#########-----B---| (the progress bar is 62 characters long and I want the letter B to show up as the 50th character)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a certain index in a string by concatenating a new string around the intended index. For example the following code replaces the letter `c` with the letter `X`. Where 2 is the intended index to replace.

In other words, this code replaces the 3rd character in the string.

```
String s = "abcde";
s = s.substring(0, 2) + "X" + s.substring(3);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29) has method `setCharAt` which can replace `character` at position with new `character`.

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(<original string>);
myName.setCharAt(<position>, <character to replace>);
```

`<position>` starts with index `0`

In your case:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("big longgggg string");
myName.setCharAt(50, 'B');
```